# ZIP - Hidden Markov model r Stan

Tags: r, rstan

I'm trying to adjust a Zero Inflated Poisson Hidden Markov Model with Stan. For the Poisson-HMM in a past forum this setting was shown. [see link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54176440/fitting-a-poisson-hmm-jags-model-with-rstan).

While to adjust the [ZIP](https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_18/stan-users-guide/zero-inflated-section.html) with the classical theory is well documented the code and model.

[image]

---

ziphsmm

```
library(ziphsmm)
set.seed(123)
prior_init <- c(0.5,0.5)
emit_init <- c(20,6)
zero_init <- c(0.5,0)
tpm <- matrix(c(0.9, 0.1, 0.2, 0.8),2,2,byrow=TRUE)
result <- hmmsim(n=100,M=2,prior=prior_init, tpm_parm=tpm,emit_parm=emit_init,zeroprop=zero_init)
y <- result$series
serie <- data.frame(y = result$series, m = result$state)

fit1 <-  fasthmmfit(y,x=NULL,ntimes=NULL,M=2,prior_init,tpm,
                    emit_init,0.5, hessian=FALSE,method="BFGS", 
                    control=list(trace=1))
fit1
$prior
            [,1]
[1,] 0.997497445
[2,] 0.002502555

$tpm
          [,1]       [,2]
[1,] 0.9264945 0.07350553
[2,] 0.3303533 0.66964673

$zeroprop
[1] 0.6342182

$emit
          [,1]
[1,] 20.384688
[2,]  7.365498

$working_parm
[1] -5.9879373 -2.5340475  0.7065877  0.5503559  3.0147840  1.9968067

$negloglik
[1] 208.823
```

Stan

```
library(rstan)

ZIPHMM <- 'data {
    int<lower=0> N;
    int<lower=0> y[N];
    int<lower=1> m;
  }

parameters {
    real<lower=0, upper=1> theta; //
    positive_ordered[m] lambda; //
    simplex[m] Gamma[m]; // tpm
  }

model {
  vector[m] log_Gamma_tr[m];
  vector[m] lp;
  vector[m] lp_p1;

  // priors
  lambda ~ gamma(0.1,0.01);
  theta ~ beta(0.05, 0.05);

  // transposing tpm and taking the log of each entry
  for(i in 1:m)
    for(j in 1:m)
      log_Gamma_tr[j, i] = log(Gamma[i, j]);

  lp = rep_vector(-log(m), m); // 

    for(n in 1:N) {
      for(j in 1:m){
        if (y[n] == 0)
          lp_p1[j] = log_sum_exp(log_Gamma_tr[j] + lp) +
                     log_sum_exp(bernoulli_lpmf(1 | theta),
                     bernoulli_lpmf(0 | theta) + poisson_lpmf(y[n] | lambda[j]));
        else
          lp_p1[j] = log_sum_exp(log_Gamma_tr[j] + lp) + 
                     bernoulli_lpmf(0 | theta) + 
                     poisson_lpmf(y[n] | lambda[j]);
                   }
      lp = lp_p1;
                  }
    target += log_sum_exp(lp);
}'
mod_ZIP <- stan(model_code = ZIPHMM, data=list(N=length(y), y=y, m=2), iter=1000, chains=1)
print(mod_ZIP,digits_summary = 3)
               mean se_mean    sd     2.5%      25%      50%      75%    97.5% n_eff  Rhat
theta         0.518   0.002 0.052    0.417    0.484    0.518    0.554    0.621   568 0.998
lambda[1]     7.620   0.039 0.787    6.190    7.038    7.619    8.194    9.132   404 1.005
lambda[2]    20.544   0.039 0.957   18.861   19.891   20.500   21.189   22.611   614 1.005
Gamma[1,1]    0.664   0.004 0.094    0.473    0.604    0.669    0.730    0.841   541 0.998
Gamma[1,2]    0.336   0.004 0.094    0.159    0.270    0.331    0.396    0.527   541 0.998
Gamma[2,1]    0.163   0.003 0.066    0.057    0.114    0.159    0.201    0.312   522 0.999
Gamma[2,2]    0.837   0.003 0.066    0.688    0.799    0.841    0.886    0.943   522 0.999
lp__       -222.870   0.133 1.683 -227.154 -223.760 -222.469 -221.691 -220.689   161 0.999
```

True values

```
real = list(tpm = tpm, 
     zeroprop = nrow(serie[serie$m == 1 & serie$y == 0, ]) / nrow(serie[serie$m == 1,]),
     emit = t(t(tapply(serie$y[serie$y != 0],serie$m[serie$y != 0], mean))))
real
$tpm
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  0.9  0.1
[2,]  0.2  0.8

$zeroprop
[1] 0.6341463

$emit
       [,1]
1 20.433333
2  7.277778
```

Estimates give quite oddly to someone could help me to know that I am doing wrong. As we see the estimates of stan zeroprop = 0.518 while the real value is 0.634, on the other hand the values of the t.p.m. in stan they are quite distant and the means lambda1 = 7.62 and lambda2 = 20.54 although they approximate enough gave in different order to the real 20.43 and 7.27. I think I'm making some mistake in defining the model in Stan but I do not know which.

Comment: I will expand my question, the proportion of zeros gives quite a distance with rStan `theta` = 0.518 and the real is 0.634, the same for the values of the transition matrix. Also the average of the values `lambda1` = 7.62 and `lambda2` = 20.54, while the real ones are `lambda1` = 20.43 and `lambda2` = 7.27. That is, they are crossed.

Comment: The discrepancy for `theta` seems like it comes from fact that the `fasthmmfit` only imposes zero inflation on the first state, whereas the way you have encoded the Stan model it applies zero inflation on both states. The prior you impose on `theta` is bimodal, which is usually hard to fit. Have you tried a flat prior on `theta` and only impose it on the one state?

Comment: How could I modify the code to impose the theta value, only in the first state? I do not know how to do it, I appreciate your help.

Comment: "*[zeroprop] real value is 0.634*" From your original HMM parameters, the real value for `zeroprop` is 0.5. Do you want a model that does best at recovering the true HMM parameters, or do you want an exact reimplementation of this SGD-based MAP estimator, but using Stan? If the latter, `rstan::optimizing` is what one uses for MAP estimates. Also, you probably shouldn't be initializing `fasthmmfit` with the true parameters if you want a realistic characterization of its behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I don't know the inner workings of the ZIP-HMM fitting algorithm, there are some obvious differences in what you have implemented in the Stan model and how the ZIP-HMM optimization algorithm describes itself.  Addressing these appears to be sufficient to generate similar results.

## Differences Between the Models

#### Initial State Probability

The values that the ZIP-HMM estimates, specifically `fit1$prior`, indicate that it includes an ability to learn a probability for initial state.  However, in the Stan model, this is fixed to 1:1

```
lp = rep_vector(-log(m), m);
```

This should be changed to allow the model to estimate an initial state.

#### Priors on Parameters (optional)

The Stan model has non-flat priors on `lambda` and `theta`, but presumably the ZIP-HMM is not weighting the specific values it arrives. If one wanted to more realistically mimic the ZIP-HMM, then flat priors would be better. However, the ability to have non-flat priors in Stan is really an opportunity to develop a more well-tuned model than is achievable with standard HMM inference algorithms.

#### Zero-Inflation on State 1

From the documentation of the `fasthmmfit` method

> Fast gradient descent / stochastic gradient descent algorithm to learn the parameters in a specialized zero-inflated hidden Markov model, **where zero-inflation only happens in State 1**. [emphasis added]

The Stan model assumes zero-inflation on all states. This is likely why the estimated `theta` value is deflated relative to the ZIP-HMM MAP estimate.

#### State Ordering

When estimating discrete latent states or clusters in Stan, one can use an **ordered vector** as a trick to [mitigate against label switching issues](https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_18/stan-users-guide/label-switching-problematic-section.html).  This is effectively achieved here with

```
positive_ordered[m] lambda;
```

However, since the ZIP-HMM only has zero-inflation on the first state, correctly implementing this behavior in Stan requires prior knowledge of what the rank of the `lambda` is for the "first" state.  This seems very problematic for generalizing this code.  For now, let's just move forward under the assumption that we can always recover this information somehow. In this specific case, we will assume that state 1 in the HMM has the higher `lambda` value, and therefore will be state 2 in the Stan model.

## Updated Stan Model

Incorporating the above changes in the model should be something like

#### Stan Model

```cpp
data {
  int<lower=0> N;    // length of chain
  int<lower=0> y[N]; // emissions
  int<lower=1> m;    // num states
}

parameters {
  simplex[m] start_pos;         // initial pos probs
  real<lower=0, upper=1> theta; // zero-inflation parameter
  positive_ordered[m] lambda;   // emission poisson params
  simplex[m] Gamma[m];          // transition prob matrix
}

model {
  vector[m] log_Gamma_tr[m];
  vector[m] lp;
  vector[m] lp_p1;

  // transposing tpm and taking the log of each entry
  for (i in 1:m) {
    for (j in 1:m) { 
      log_Gamma_tr[j, i] = log(Gamma[i, j]);
    }
  }

  // initial position log-lik
  lp = log(start_pos);

  for (n in 1:N) {
    for (j in 1:m) {
      // log-lik for state
      lp_p1[j] = log_sum_exp(log_Gamma_tr[j] + lp);

      // log-lik for emission
      if (j == 2) { // assuming only state 2 has zero-inflation
        if (y[n] == 0) {
          lp_p1[j] += log_mix(theta, 0, poisson_lpmf(0 | lambda[j]));
        } else {
          lp_p1[j] += log1m(theta) + poisson_lpmf(y[n] | lambda[j]);
        }
      } else {
        lp_p1[j] += poisson_lpmf(y[n] | lambda[j]);
      }
    }
    lp = lp_p1; // log-lik for next position
  }
  target += log_sum_exp(lp);
}
```

### MAP Estimate

Loading the above as a string variable `code.ZIPHMM`, we first compile it and run a MAP estimate (since MAP estimation is going to behave most like the HMM fitting algorithm):

```r
model.ZIPHMM <- stan_model(model_code=code.ZIPHMM)

// note the use of some initialization on the params,
// otherwise it can occasionally converge to strange extrema
map.ZIPHMM <- optimizing(model.ZIPHMM, algorithm="BFGS",
                         data=list(N=length(y), y=y, m=2),
                         init=list(theta=0.5, lambda=c(5,10)))
```

Examining the estimated parameters

```
> map.ZIPHMM$par
start_pos[1] start_pos[2]        
9.872279e-07 9.999990e-01 

theta    
6.342449e-01 

lambda[1]    lambda[2]   
7.370525e+00 2.038363e+01 

Gamma[1,1]   Gamma[2,1]   Gamma[1,2]   Gamma[2,2] 
6.700871e-01 7.253215e-02 3.299129e-01 9.274678e-01
```

shows they closely reflect the values that `fasthmmfit` inferred, excepting that the state orders are switched.

### Sampling the Posterior

This model can also be run with MCMC to infer a full posterior,

```
samples.ZIPHMM <- stan(model_code = code.ZIPHMM, 
                       data=list(N=length(y), y=y, m=2), 
                       iter=2000, chains=4)
```

which samples well and yields similar results (and without any parameter initializations)

```
> samples.ZIPHMM
Inference for Stan model: b29a2b7e93b53c78767aa4b0c11b62a0.
4 chains, each with iter=2000; warmup=1000; thin=1; 
post-warmup draws per chain=1000, total post-warmup draws=4000.

                mean se_mean   sd    2.5%     25%     50%     75%   97.5% n_eff Rhat
start_pos[1]    0.45    0.00 0.29    0.02    0.20    0.43    0.69    0.97  6072    1
start_pos[2]    0.55    0.00 0.29    0.03    0.31    0.57    0.80    0.98  6072    1
theta           0.63    0.00 0.05    0.53    0.60    0.63    0.67    0.73  5710    1
lambda[1]       7.53    0.01 0.72    6.23    7.02    7.49    8.00    9.08  4036    1
lambda[2]      20.47    0.01 0.87   18.83   19.87   20.45   21.03   22.24  5964    1
Gamma[1,1]      0.65    0.00 0.11    0.43    0.57    0.65    0.72    0.84  5664    1
Gamma[1,2]      0.35    0.00 0.11    0.16    0.28    0.35    0.43    0.57  5664    1
Gamma[2,1]      0.08    0.00 0.03    0.03    0.06    0.08    0.10    0.16  5605    1
Gamma[2,2]      0.92    0.00 0.03    0.84    0.90    0.92    0.94    0.97  5605    1
lp__         -214.76    0.04 1.83 -219.21 -215.70 -214.43 -213.43 -212.25  1863    1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help and the time dedicated, for the elaboration of the code this impressive. Apparently it was what he needed. I only have two questions. 1. Is it possible to change the order of the states in Stan to match as in ziphsmm? since in a 3-state model the order of the probability transition matrix would be a bit confusing. 2. If the code j = 2 is omitted, it is assumed that there is inflation in all the states, and therefore a more realistic model would be created?

Comment: @RafaelDíaz 1) You could add a transformed parameter to the model where you reorder the `lambda` vector. 2) To make everything inflated, keep only the code block under the `if (j==2) {...}` statement, but remove the conditional.

Comment: My friend, thank you very much, you saved my life, this was what I was looking for and I believe that you have earned the reward.